# How to automatically rename files when they get into folder

Tags: windows

I've been trying to find a program or some sort of app to run all the time and check one folder. If any document would be saved in the folder it would rename it like `file1.png` the next one `file2.png`.

Comment: [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 0):

Transnomino has an automation feature that allows to automatically rename any file dropped in a folder using a specified renaming Recipe. The Apple Script that does this looks something like this:

```
on adding folder items to theAttachedFolder after receiving theNewItems
    tell application "Finder" to set thePath to POSIX path of theAttachedFolder
    return do shell script ¬
        "open -a Transnomino --args -d \"" & thePath & "\" -r \"" & thePath & ".recipe\""
end adding folder items to
```

A complete guide how this can be setup is described on the website of Transnomino. Here: https://transnomino.bastiaanverreijt.com/automation/index.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).